# Get pointer to file data

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I'm working on a C# application and I need to pass a pointer to a fairly large array of data (about 48 kB) to unmanaged code.  The data is stored in a file in exactly the format that it will need to be passed to the unmanaged code.

I already know I can get a pointer to the array by reading the file and then marshalling the data, like below, but I would prefer not to use this solution.

```
    const string filename = "file.bin";
    int length = (int)(new System.IO.FileInfo(filename)).Length;
    byte[] data = new byte[length];
    IntPtr ptr;

    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        fs.Read(data, 0, length);

    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, length);

    // Pass ptr to my unmanaged function
```

One reason that I don't want to use the above code is that the unmanaged code will retain the pointer and continue to reference it, so I can't deallocate the memory until I'm shutting down my application.

**My question is:**  Is there a better way to do this?  Ideally, I'd like to pass a pointer directly to the file data (or maybe a managed memory stream) so that I would not have to copy the data as much or worry about possible memory leaks.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I suggest fixing up the title to better reflect the question.

Comment: Do you have any control over the unmanaged code? Is it your own or somebody else's?

Comment: I don't have control of the unmanaged code

Comment: I am not really sure to understand your whole problematic (I never played with unmanaged code), can this help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ?

Comment: @fharreau Very nice article, thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @fharreau I need to get a pointer to the data in the file, and I don't see any methods to provide a pointer.  Also, I'm not sure I'd get any advantage from using a memory mapped file since I always need to provide access to the entire file.